# React Native/Redux: Why route popped with vertical transition animation even though route pushed with horizontal animation?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, react-native

In React Native + Redux, I am able to dynamically change the `direction` property, for transition animation, for `<NavigationCardStack/>` depending on the route, as long as `direction:` property is define:

`this.props.navigation.routes[this.props.navigation.index].direction`

For example, I've defined `direction:` to be pushed as `vertical`, yet when popped, the route `pops` with `horizontal` transition animation when should have been what whichever `direction:` it was pushed with, in this case `horizontal`. What may be the issue?

Thank you in advance:

This is my set up -
Redux:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    navigation: state.navReducer,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    pushRoute: (route) => push(route),
    popRoute: () => pop(),
  }
)(NavigationRoot)
```

My reducer (`navReducer.js`):

```
const initialState = {
  index: 0,
  key: 'root',
  routes: [{
   key: 'login',
   title: 'Login',
   component: Login,
   direction: 'horizontal',
  }]
}

function navigationState (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case PUSH_ROUTE:
      if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
    return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

    case POP_ROUTE:
      if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
      return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)

   default:
     return state

  }
}

export default navigationState
```

And these methods handle push and pop and how navigation bar back (pop) button is set up:

```
  _renderScene (props) {
    const { route } = props.scene

    return (
      <route.component _handleNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)} {...route.passProps} actions={this.props}/>
    )
  }

  _handleBackAction() {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true
  }

  _handleNavigate(action) {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route)
        return true
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction()
      default:
        return false
    }
  }

renderOverlay = (sceneProps) => {
if(0 < sceneProps.scene.index)
{
  return (
    <NavigationHeader
      {...sceneProps}
      renderLeftComponent={() => {
        switch(sceneProps.scene.route.title){
          case 'Home':
            return (
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._handleBackAction()}>
                <Text}>X</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            )
          }
        }
      }
    />
  )
}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <NavigationCardStack
          direction={this.props.navigation.routes[this.props.navigation.index].direction}
          navigationState={this.props.navigation}
          onNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)}
          renderScene={this._renderScene}
          renderOverlay={this.renderOverlay}
        />
    )
  }
```

And called by components like so:

```
const route = {
  home: {
    type: 'push',
    route: {
      key: 'home',
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      direction: 'vertical',
    }
  }
}
```